# Uploading file with multer in nodejs returns req.file undefined and empty req.body

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multer

So, I have a problem with uploading files with multer in nodejs. After my first tries there was just no return and no file in my destination folder. I logged the body to check and it returns `[Object: null prototype] {}`. Return of `req.file` is `undefined`.

my route file: workflow.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const multer = require('multer')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (request, file, callback) {
      callback(null, "./public/data/satelliteimage/");
  },
  filename: function (request, file, callback) {
      fileName=file.originalname;
      callback(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

const uploadDest = multer({storage:storage})


router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('workflow');
});


router.post("/uploadSatelliteimage", uploadDest.single("satellitenbildInput"), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.file);
  console.log(req.body);

  res.render('workflow');
})


module.exports = router;
```

my view file: workflow.pug

```
extends layout

block content
    br
    br
    .container
        .row.justify-content-md-center
            .col-md-3
            .col-md-6
                div#form_div_sat.active-form
                    form(action='/workflow/uploadSatelliteimage' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data")
                        label.col-md-4.col-form-label.fw-bolder(for='satellitenbild') Satellitenbild
                        input#satellitenbildInput.form-control.form-control-lg(type='file' name="satellitenbild" accept="image/png")
                        button#btn_satellite.btn.btn-primary.mb-2 Weiter
                br
                br
                br
            .col-md-3
        .row.justify-content-md-center
            .col-md-1 
            .col-md-4 
                div#form_div_train
                    form
                        label.col-md-4.col-form-label.fw-bolder(for='trainModell') Trainiertes Modell
                        input#trainMod.form-control.form-control-lg(type='file' name="trainModell" accept=" " enctype="multipart/form-data" disabled=true)
                    button#btn_trainMod.btn.btn-secondary.mb-2.disabled Weiter
            .col-md-2 
                br
                br
                h3.text-center oder
            .col-md-4 
                div#form_div_untrain
                    form
                        label.col-md-4.col-form-label.fw-bolder(for='untrainModell') Nicht-trainiertes Modell
                        input#untrainMod.form-control.form-control-lg(type='file' name="untrainModell" accept=" " enctype="multipart/form-data" disabled=true)
                    button#btn_untrainMod.btn.btn-secondary.mb-2.disabled Weiter
                br
                div#form_div
                    form
                        input#testR.form-control(type='text' name="testR", disabled = '')
                        button.btn.btn-secondary.mb-2(type='submit').disabled AOA berechnen
            .col-md-1

block scripts 
  script(src="/javascripts/workflowJS.js" defer)
```

I googled a lot and found some stackoverflow questions but the answers didn't help me.
My guesses are, that it has something to do with `body-parser`, but that's only for text and `multer` should be the right one. Or the order of the forms, body is not populated yet? Or something completely different.

I hope to find a solution with your help. Thanks!

EDIT: I could delete this to avoid the embarrasement but its now a memorial for me to always check variable name. Maybe at some point i can look back at this and laugh about myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the upload file field must be identical on both frontend and backend, and you have a mismatch here:

server:

```
uploadDest.single("satellitenbildInput"),
```

frontend:

```
name="satellitenbild" accept="image/png"
```

so, instead of `satellitenbildInput` and `satellitenbild`, they need to match:

server:

```
uploadDest.single("satellitenbildInput"),
```

frontend:

```
name="satellitenbildInput" accept="image/png"
```

Also, you seem to be uploading multiple files, but from different fields: `trainModell` and `untrainModell`, so you'll need to use [`.fields`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#fieldsfields) method, where for every file field you provide an object with file field name, in an array, and also the files would be stored in `req.files`, so your route should look like this:

```
router.post("/uploadSatelliteimage", uploadDest.fields([{
    name: 'satellitenbildInput',
    maxCount: 1
}, {
    name: 'trainModell',
    maxCount: 1
}, {
    name: 'untrainModell',
    maxCount: 1
}]), function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.files);
    console.log(req.body);

    res.render('workflow');
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to fix this problem for quite some time now and changed the name at one point to try something...  And i only try to upload the satellite imagery, so you fixed my problem with the first tip :)